Having trouble reading/writing from SQLite db in .NET MAUI App (Android)
I'm following Microsoft's documentation for SQLite in MAUI apps, but I don't think I've ever gotten this up and running. I am using DI to register my database builder.Services.AddSingleton<CalisthenicsTrackerDatabase>(); as well as my ViewModel/View.
I've created a Constants class to hold the db path. Since we're using the AppDataDirectory, we should have no problem with permissions to read/write to that file (ideally, correct me if I'm wrong):
public const string DatabaseFilename = "calisthenicstracker.db3";

public const SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags Flags = SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite | SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags.Create | SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags.SharedCache;

public static string DatabasePath => Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, DatabaseFilename);

As well as db class. Here, I am utilizing the "Lazy Initialization" Microsoft recommends. I am also attempting to input "Seed Data", which hopefully should be pre-populated into the db. You'll also see I've been erasing the existing file each time, which is intentional just because I'm testing the seed data:
SQLiteAsyncConnection Database;

public CalisthenicsTrackerDatabase()
{
    if (File.Exists(Constants.DatabasePath))
    {
        File.Delete(Constants.DatabasePath);
    }
    Init();
}

async Task Init()
{

    if (Database is not null)
        return;
    Database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(Constants.DatabasePath, Constants.Flags);
    var result = await Database.CreateTableAsync<Exercise>();

    await SeedData();
}

private async Task SeedData()
{
    List<Exercise> DefaultExercises = new List<Exercise>()
    {
        new Exercise()
        {
            ExerciseID = 1,
            Name = "Planche"
        },
        new Exercise()
        {
            ExerciseID = 2,
            Name = "Front Lever"
        }
    };
    foreach (var exercise in DefaultExercises)
    {
        await Database.InsertAsync(exercise);
    }
}

public async Task<List<Exercise>> GetExercisesAsync()
{
    await Init();
    return await Database.Table<Exercise>().ToListAsync();
}

public async Task<Exercise> GetExerciseAsync(int id)
{
    await Init();
    return await Database.Table<Exercise>().Where(i => i.ExerciseID == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}

public async Task<int> SaveExerciseAsync(Exercise exercise)
{
    await Init();
    if (exercise.ExerciseID != 0)
        return await Database.UpdateAsync(exercise);
    else
        return await Database.InsertAsync(exercise);
}

public async Task<int> DeleteExerciseAsync(Exercise exercise)
{
    await Init();
    return await Database.DeleteAsync(exercise);
}

My ViewModel will invoke this code:
var exerciseList = await _database.GetExercisesAsync();
MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
{
    Exercises.Clear();
    foreach (var e in exerciseList)
    {
        Exercises.Add(e);
    }
});

Then the binding should take care of the rest.
I've confirmed that my binding is correct by testing another collection build right from my view model. I've also logged the value of "Exercises", which is null each time. Any suggestions?

What is the specific problem you’re stuck on?  Why do you think this isn’t working?  Are you getting any errors or exceptions?

I test your code , but everything works fine, the problem lies in the code related to Exercises. Can you show me a more complete code about viewmodel ？
